# How do you remove a Ruby on Rails app from a production server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to replace our existing Ruby on Rails application with a new version of the site in PHP, but I'm not sure how to remove the rails app from our shared VPS server.

Is there a way to delete the app via FTP or some way to remove it in Cpanel?  The developers set it up to use a custom deployment script. Are there any typical uninstall scripts that might remove it?

Ideally, I'd like to avoid completely re-provisioning the server instance because I don't want to lose our blog database and email accounts.

Sorry for such a dumb noob question, but I'd really be grateful for some advice.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If its on linux, it should be at /var/www. Remove the database entries and put the PHP versions there too.